# tensor product and space of multilinear forms

Tags: tensors, bilinear-form

### Abstract definition

I'm giving here the [definition of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) trough universal property.

A *tensor product* of $V$ and $W$ is a pair $(T,h)$ where $T$ is a vector space and $h:V\times W\to T$ is a bilinear map such that for every bilinear map $f: V\times W\to Z$, there exists a unique linear map $\tilde f:T\to Z$ such that $f=\tilde f\circ h$.

One can show that every tensor product of $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

### Usual realization

Most of people define the tensor product $V^*\otimes V^*$ as the set of bilinear maps over $V$. Example [from here](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/16F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec16.pdf):

A function $T:V^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a tensor if it is bilinear.

### My question

If I understand correctly, the space of bilinear forms over $V$ is a tensor product.

QUESTION: what is the function $h$ such that $(L_2(V,\mathbb{R}),h)$ is a tensor product of $V^*$ and $V^*$ ?

I made a guess here: [Universal property of multilinear maps (how to make them a tensor product)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666598/universal-property-of-multilinear-maps-how-to-make-them-a-tensor-product) but I'm not sure it works.

Comment: This is $V^*\otimes V^*$.

Comment: @TedShifrin fixed, thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a function template like $V^*\times V^*\xrightarrow{h} V^* \otimes V^*$ such that $h(g_h\varepsilon^h,g_k\varepsilon^k )=g_{hk}\varepsilon^h\otimes\varepsilon^k$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2479844.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{\alpha_i\}$ be a basis of $V^*$ and $\{\beta_j\}$ be a basis of $W^*$.

We define $h:V^*\times W^*\to L_2(V\times W,\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
h(\xi,\sigma)(v,w)=\xi(v)\sigma(w).
$$
It has the property that the elements $h(\alpha_i,\beta_j)$ form a basis of $L_2(V\times W,\mathbb{R})$.

Now we prove that the couple $\big( L_2(V\times W,\mathbb{R},h) \big)$ is a tensor product for $V^*$ and $W^*$.

If $f:V^*\times W^*\to Z$ is a bilinear map, it has its "matrix" given by the element $f_{ij}=f(\alpha_i,\beta_j)\in Z$.

The trick is to consider the map $\tilde f:V^*\times W^*\to Z$ defined by
$$
\tilde f\Big( \sum_{ij}a_{ij}h(\alpha_i,\beta_j) \Big)=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}f_{ij}.
$$

It is not so complicated to check that $\tilde f\circ h=f$.